# We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xls' after editing file with openxml

Tags: c#, openxml

I have written a piece of code that grabs data from a database and then I try to sort it by region and have it export to an excel file. Each sheet within the excel has the data of each region. I keep getting this error:

> We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xls'. Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can?

I can't seem to figure out where I have coded something wrong within here to cause this. Here is my code:

```
private void AddSheet(SpreadsheetDocument document, WorkbookPart workbookPart, Sheets sheets, string sheetName, UInt32 sheetNumber, List<RentalFeeReportingRecord> currentRecordList)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> listofCoreBankingIds = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    listofCoreBankingIds = currentRecordList.Select(x => new { id = x.CoreBankingId, regionName = x.RegionName }).Distinct().ToDictionary(y => y.id, y => y.regionName);
    foreach (var coreBankingId in listofCoreBankingIds.OrderBy(x => x.Value))
    {
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart1 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        string previousCurrency = null;
        string previousRegionName = null;
        int recordCounter = 1;
        double previousTotal = 0;

        Worksheet worksheet1 = new Worksheet();
        SheetData sheetData1 = new SheetData();

        Row rowInSheet1 = new Row();
        Row firstRow = new Row();
        Row lastRow = new Row();

        rowInSheet1.Append(
          excelController.ConstructCell("Region", CellValues.String, 3), excelController.ConstructCell("Merchant - Terminal", CellValues.String, 3), 
          excelController.ConstructCell("Fee Charged", CellValues.String, 3), 
          excelController.ConstructCell("Currency", CellValues.String, 3), 
          excelController.ConstructCell("Processing Date", CellValues.String, 3), 
          excelController.ConstructCell("Description", CellValues.String, 3)
        );

        sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);

        foreach (var currentRecord in currentRecordList.OrderBy(x => x.RegionName).ThenBy(z => z.Currency).ThenBy(y => y.DateProcessed))
        {
            if (coreBankingId.Key == currentRecord.CoreBankingId)
            {

                string regionName = currentRecord.RegionName;

                string currentCurrency = currentRecord.Currency;

                double currentTotal = currentRecord.TotalFeeAmount;
                string EmptySpace = string.Empty;

                string merchant = currentRecord.MerchantRecord.MerchantID + " - " + currentRecord.MerchantTerminalRecord.terminalID;

                if (currentRecord.IsPinPad)
                {
                    merchant = merchant + " - PIN Pad";
                }

                string description = currentRecord.TerminalRecord.description;
                if (currentRecord.IsProRated)
                {
                    int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentRecord.DeployedDate.Year, currentRecord.DeployedDate.Month);

                    description = currentRecord.TerminalRecord.description + " (" + currentRecord.MonthlyFee + " Fee \\ " + days.ToString() + " Days) * " + currentRecord.DaysActive.ToString() + " Days Active";
                }

                rowInSheet1 = new Row();
                firstRow = new Row();
                lastRow = new Row();

                if (recordCounter == currentRecordList.Count() && previousRegionName == regionName)
                {
                    firstRow.Append(
                      excelController.ConstructCell(regionName, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(merchant, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFee.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 1),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.DateProcessed.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(description, CellValues.String, 2)
                    );
                    sheetData1.Append(firstRow);


                    rowInSheet1.Append(
                      excelController.ConstructCell("TOTALS", CellValues.String, 6),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFeeAmount.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 6),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 6),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2)

                    );
                    sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);

                }
                else if (recordCounter == currentRecordList.Count())
                {
                    rowInSheet1.Append(
                      excelController.ConstructCell(regionName, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(merchant, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFee.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 1),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.DateProcessed.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(description, CellValues.String, 2)
                    );

                    sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);

                    lastRow.Append(
                      excelController.ConstructCell("TOTALS", CellValues.String, 6),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFeeAmount.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 6),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 6),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                      excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2)

                    );
                    sheetData1.Append(lastRow);

                }
                else
                {
                    if ((previousCurrency == null && previousRegionName == null) || (previousCurrency == currentCurrency && previousRegionName == regionName))
                    {
                        rowInSheet1.Append(
                          excelController.ConstructCell(regionName, CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(merchant, CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFee.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 1),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.DateProcessed.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(description, CellValues.String, 2)
                        );
                        sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);
                        previousCurrency = currentCurrency;
                        previousTotal = currentTotal;
                        previousRegionName = regionName;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rowInSheet1.Append(
                          excelController.ConstructCell("TOTALS", CellValues.String, 6),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(previousTotal.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 6),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(previousCurrency, CellValues.String, 6),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2)

                        );
                        sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);

                        Row emptyRow;
                        emptyRow = new Row();
                        emptyRow.Append(
                          excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(" ", CellValues.String, 2)
                        );
                        sheetData1.Append(emptyRow);

                        Row row;
                        row = new Row();
                        row.Append(
                          excelController.ConstructCell(regionName, CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(merchant, CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.TotalFee.ToString("N2"), CellValues.String, 1),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.Currency, CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(currentRecord.DateProcessed.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), CellValues.String, 2),
                          excelController.ConstructCell(description, CellValues.String, 2)
                        );
                        sheetData1.Append(row);

                        previousCurrency = currentCurrency;
                        previousTotal = currentTotal;
                        previousRegionName = regionName;
                    }
                    recordCounter++;
                }
            }

        }

        Columns columns = excelController.AutoSize(sheetData1);

        worksheet1.AppendChild(columns);
        worksheet1.AppendChild(sheetData1);
        worksheetPart1.Worksheet = worksheet1;

        Sheet sheet1 = new Sheet()
        {
            Id = document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1),
            SheetId = sheetNumber,
            Name = previousRegionName
        };

        sheets.Append(sheet1);
    }
}
```

I have tried debugging as much as I can but can't seem to figure out where the problem lies.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have made a small adjustment where i compare recordcounter to currentrecordlist.count() to ```recordCounter == currentRecordList.Where(x => x.CoreBankingId == coreBankingId.Key).Count()``` this has solved ony of my issues but the main issue of the corrupted file is still there

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies with the `sheetNumber` It must be incremented or else Excel thinks all the sheets have the same sheetnumber. This was fixed by adding `sheetNumber++` after appending every sheet.